# sqlalchemy: How do I enforce date range on column?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Here is how my column looks

```
financial_day_of_month = Column('financial_day_of_month', Integer,
                                    nullable=False, default=1)
```

I want to enforce that `min=1` and `max=31` for this column. I am using `PostgreSQL` as the backend

Although I can enforce this logic on business layer, I prefer to enforce it on the persistence layer

Is there a way to support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [check constraint](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#check-constraint), something like:

```
class FooTable(DeclBase):
    financial_day_of_month = Column('financial_day_of_month', Integer,
                                        nullable=False, default=1)
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('financial_day_of_month between 1 and 31', name='check1'),
        {})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is define a [new type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/xtypes.html) in your database and then create your own type in SQLAlchemy using the [decorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html).